# webflux: map preserving first object

Tags: spring-webflux

Here my first code:

```java
public Mono<QdCFPresenter> store(QdCFPresenter qdcf) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(qdcf)
            .map(this.persistencyMapper::toPersistency)
            .map(this.qdcfRepository::save)
            .flatMap(this.presenterMapper::toPresenter);
    }
```

My `qdcf` object is:

1. mapped to persistency model
2. saved on database
3. mapped to presenter model

I need to create an audit after `qdcfRepository.save` method.

I'm trying that:

```java
public Mono<QdCFPresenter> store(QdCFPresenter qdcf) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(qdcf)
            .map(this.persistencyMapper::toPersistency)
            .map(this.qdcfRepository::save)
            .orElse(Mono.empty())
            .map(this::buildAuditoria)
            .map(this.auditoriaService::store)
            .flatMap(this.presenterMapper::toPresenter);
    }
```

Nevertheless, last step is telling me:

> type QdCFPresenterMapper does not define toPresenter(Mono) that is applicable here

Shortly, is telling me that I'm passing an `Auditoria` object to method `toPresenter(Mono<AuditoriaPresenter>)`.

Is there any way do that whithout losing initial Mono object?

Comment: There are many possibilities : use `transform` instead of `flatMap`, or remove the flatMap and call return `presenterapper.toPresenter(Optional.ofNullable(qdcf.map(...)...);`, or modify your flatMap as follow : `.flatMap(auditoria -> presenterMapper.toPresenter(Mono.just(auditoria))`. But, another question: `toPresenter` expects a `Mono<Auditoria>` as input, or a `Mono<AuditoriaPresenter>` ? Because in the later case (with the information currently provided), I think you also miss a step to transform an Auditoria to AuditoriaPresenter.

Comment: In your example you are mixing Java Streams Api and Reactive API. I would rather use Reactive API only starting with `Mono.justOrEmpty(qdcf)` and then use `map` for sync operations and `flatMap` for async operations that return `Mono`.

Comment: @Alex Look closely. He does not use java stream. He uses an Optional that result in a Mono. But I agree with you: starting straight with a mono would be more consistent regarding API homogeneity. Anyway, not enough details to provide a consistent answer. We miss too much context information : what are the signatures of used methods, and what is going on with Auditoria and AuditoriaPresenter (cf. second part of my comment above)